# UISearchController not updating

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I am developing using xcode 6.2 in ios8 and swift, I am trying to implement a UISearchController inside a UITableViewController which could be updated after the search, I wrote some simple code just to check if it works, but when I compile, the search bar is there, but when I enter the text and hit search, nothing happens:

here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class searchresult: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var result:[String] = ["a","b","c"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var searchcon = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)
        searchcon.delegate = self
        searchcon.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchcon.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchcon.searchBar
        searchcon.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchcon.searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = true
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchcon.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = result[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return result.count
    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        println("updating")
        result = ["1"]
        self.tableView.reloadData()   
    }
}
```

Comment: Just try changing `self` to `nil` in `var searchcon = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)`, because it tries to create a new `searchResultsController` to display the results

Answer (score 2):

As Praveen Gowda IV said, you wanna change the `searchResultsController` from `self` to `nil`. Also you need to declare your `searchcon` outside `viewDidLoad`:

```
var searchcon = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // your implementation
}
```

However, the behaviour you get might be not what you want because `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` gets called before the search:

> Called when the search bar becomes the first responder or when the
>   user makes changes inside the search bar. ([Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchResultsUpdating_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchResultsUpdating/updateSearchResultsForSearchController:))

Comment: This works, but I do not fully understand why I have to initialise searchon outside viewdidload, could you please explaine ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant 'declare', not 'initialise'. 

Your code doesn't work because of [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). It gets rid of your `searchcon` as soon as `viewDidAppear` completes so by the time something updates the object is gone.

To check that, create a subclass of  `UISearchController` and implement the `deinit` method so that it prints a message. Make `searchcon` to be an instance of that subclass. Now you can easily get to know when your object dies.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, you need to change `self` to `null` in the initialization of `UISearchController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var searchcon = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchcon.delegate = self
    searchcon.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchcon.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchcon.searchBar
    searchcon.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchcon.searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = true
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchcon.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

}
```

What user3694363 said about `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` getting called even before text is changed, is correct. But you can follow the below trick to prevent doing anything when it becomes the first responder

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        // No need to update anything if we're being dismissed.
        if !searchController.active {
            return
        }

        // do the filtering here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code With other stuff in as it is.

```
class searchresult: UITableViewController {      

var searchcon = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

searchcon.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchcon.searchBar.sizeToFit()
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchcon.searchBar
searchcon.searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = true
self.definesPresentationContext = true
searchcon.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
}
```